# Given $X_1, X_2, ...$ are independent random variables uniform on $[-a_1, a_1], [-a_2, a_2], ...$, show that $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i \rightarrow 0$ a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Given $X_1, ...$ defined as above for some sequence of $a_n>0$, and let $Y_n = \prod_{i=1}^n X_i$, show $Y_n \stackrel{a.s}{\rightarrow} 0$ if $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n < 2$.

Here's my attempt, will be grateful if someone helps me to check this.

To show $Y_n \stackrel{a.s}{\rightarrow} 0$, it suffices to show that $\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq 1 \, \text{i.o.}) = 0$. To show this, assume the extreme case that $a_1, a_2, ... > 1$, and compute $$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{E} \left[1_{\{|X_i|<1\}} - 1_{\{|X_i|> 1\}}\right] = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{2}{2a_i} - \frac{2(a_i-1)}{2a_i} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i} - \frac{1}{2} = \infty,
$$
since $\limsup a_n < 2$. Therefore,  $|X_i| < 1$ infinitely often. Hence, $Y_n = \prod_{i=1}^n X_i = 0$ almost surely.

My second question is, will the a.s. convergence of $Y_n$ still hold if its $\limsup a_n \leq 2$? I suspect not, as $\limsup a_n = 2$ could just mean a constant sequence $a_1 = a_2 = ... = 2$. But how can I prove this claim?

Comment: The first step is wrong. If $X_n=1$ for all $n$ then $P(|X_n|>1\, i.o.)=0$ but $Y_n=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: How does $\lim \sup a_n=2$ imply that $a_n=2$ for all $n$?

Comment: A thought.  Consider $|X_i|$, uniform on $(0,a_i)$, then study $\sum \log|X_i|$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But $P(X_i = 1) = 0$, so a.s. this won't happen? For the $\limsup a_n = 2$, i was just thinking of an extreme case.

Comment: But still you have to justify your first step if you want to use it.

Comment: @GEdgar hmm i actually tried that, but got no where. Basically what I did was to let $U_i = Unif(-1,1)$, study $P(\prod a_i |U_i| > \epsilon)$ for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, taking logs and study $P(\sum \log |U_i| > \epsilon/2^n)$, where the $2$ came from the $\limsup$, but this was getting no where, Perhaps you can guide me on how to do this? If we can show this to be true for any $\epsilon>0$, then a.s. convergence follows

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy right, would changing the $>$ to $\geq$ in $P(|X_i|\geq 1 \text{ i.o.})$ help?

Comment: No. An infinite product of numbers each less than $1$ can be $>0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy then, any suggestions on how to prove this? this is a past year qualifying exam question from my math dept

Comment: As mentioned by GEdgar you have to study $\sum \log |X_i|$. This is a series of independent r.v.'s and we want it to diverge a.s.

Comment: $\sum \log |X_n|$ is a random walk where each step with $a_n < e$ has negative expectation.  Is there an appropriate theorem for that situation?